# php custom json_decode, some values are not enclosed by double quotations

Tags: php, json

Our server does not have the latest PHP versions, thus I cannot use json_decode. I tried to use the PEAR one: http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps, but the dataset is huge and it got the 30 seconds time out error - 30 seconds is unacceptable run time anyways.

I stumbled across this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#108552
It almost works.

My JSON is in this form:

```
[{"number1":3,"number2":5,"time":"Jul 30, 2012 1:05:07 PM","value1":"aa","value2":"bb"}]
```

As you can see, the "number1" and "number2" fields have values that aren't enclosed by double quotations, which breaks the custom json_decode.

Does anyone know how to modify or provide a json_decode that can overcome this?

Comment: First result in Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707903/php-json-decode-not-supported-any-alternatives

Comment: why don't you modify your JSON to bring it to the right format (with double quotes)?

Comment: @message I said in my post, the PEAR solution times out for me, and the Zend solution requires I use Zend.

Comment: @haynar I am not inclined to modify the service that serves up the JSON with double quotes because that would mean I have to change the type of the model and modify a bunch of code all over the place... mainly changing int to String I believe.

Comment: Use http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp which provides a near 100% compatible `json_decode()` fallback.

Comment: but here `json_decode` will fail anyway, because this is not valid JSON string, so you need to use something unusual, maybe even write your own `json_decode`

Comment: Also don't use the questionable code from php.net comments. While I strongly disagree with the commonplace mindless scaremongering regarding `eval`, this is one area where it definitely shouldn't be utilized. (Don't pipe user input into code!)

Comment: @mario That upgradephp works very well, even with my JSON input. I will keep that in mind, your note about the questionable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I used http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp which seems to work as a good json_decode() fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your PHP:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

In the your javascript, use:

```
// Fetch the JSON text
var jsonFetch = $.ajax({
   url:"http://localhost/yourphp.php",
   async:false,
   cache:false,
}).responseText;
// Parse it so it will more formatted the right way
jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonFetch);
```

Comment: I have to call this on the PHP side.

Comment: header("Content-type: application/json"); = PHP and the other code is in your javascript